# C++ Win32 Error

Tags: c++, winapi

I made a class for Win32 and I have no idea why this error happens.

This is the code:

main.cpp

```
using namespace std;
#include "WindowManager.h"

#define   WIDTH     700
#define   HEIGHT    500
#define   VERSION   0.1

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPreviousInstance,LPSTR lpcmdline,int nCmdShow)
{
    WindowManager window("TalkToMe", 100, 100, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    while(window.isWindowOpen())
    {
        window.PekMessage();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

WindowManager.h

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>

class WindowManager
{
private:
    MSG msg;
    HWND window;

    int stat;
public:
    WindowManager(LPCTSTR title,int x, int y, int width, int height);
    ~WindowManager();
    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND winhan,UINT uint_Message,WPARAM parameter1,LPARAM parameter2);

    inline bool isWindowOpen()   { return stat != -1; }
    int  getStat()               { return stat; }
    void PekMessage();
};
```

WindowManager.cpp

```
#include "WindowManager.h"

void WindowManager::PekMessage()
{
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, window, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowManager::WindowProcedure(HWND winhan,UINT uint_Message,WPARAM parameter1,LPARAM parameter2)
{
    switch(uint_Message)
    {
        case 16: // exit button
            stat = -1;
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(winhan,uint_Message,parameter1,parameter2);
}

WindowManager::WindowManager(LPCTSTR title,int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    stat = 0;

    WNDCLASSEX wnd;
    wnd.cbSize = sizeof(wnd);
    wnd.style  = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wnd.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wnd.cbClsExtra  = 0;
    wnd.cbWndExtra  = 0;
    wnd.hInstance   = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wnd.hIcon       = NULL;
    wnd.hCursor     = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wnd.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(NULL);
    wnd.lpszClassName = "TalkToMe";
    wnd.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wnd.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    RegisterClassEx(&wnd);

    window = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, wnd.lpszClassName, title, 
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, width, height,NULL, NULL, 
        GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
}

WindowManager::~WindowManager()
{
    DestroyWindow(window);
}
```

This is the weird build failure:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Client, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  WindowManager.cpp
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\talktome\talktome\windowmanager.cpp(31): error C3867: 'WindowManager::WindowProcedure': function call missing argument list; use '&WindowManager::WindowProcedure' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\talktome\talktome\windowmanager.cpp(31): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'LRESULT (__stdcall WindowManager::* )(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'WNDPROC'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>  Generating Code...
1> Compiling...
1>  Main.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Even if your program worked, `PeekMessage` does not block the caller.  This means that your program will consume CPU even when idle.  You should use `GetMessage`.

Comment: Looks like the answer is in the error message: &WindowManager::WindowProcedure. See http://www.crawfordology.net/tips/code/c++/member-pointers.html

Answer (score 4):

This is to be expected. `WindowManager::WindowManager` has a hidden `this` argument, thus it does not respect the definition required for `wnd.lpfnWndProc`.

To work around this issue, you need to define a helper function as follows:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK HelperWindowProcedure(HWND winhan,UINT uint_Message,WPARAM parameter1,LPARAM parameter2)
{
    if (uint_Message == WM_CREATE)
    {
       /* Retrieve "this" sent through CreateWindowEx */
       WindowManager *wm = (WindowManager *)(((LPCREATESTRUCT) lParam)->lpCreateParams);
       /* And store it as window-private date */
       SetWindowLongPtr(winhan, GWLP_USERDATA, wm);
    }

    /* Retrieve WindowManager from window-private data */
    WindowManager *wm = (WindowManager *)GetWindowLongPtr(winhan, GWLP_USERDATA);
    /* Forward window message to WindowManager */
    wm->WindowProcedure(winhan, uint_Message, parameter1, parameter2);
}

WindowManager::WindowManager()
{
    ...
    /* use helper window procedure */
    wnd.lpfnWndProc = HelperWindowProcedure;
    ...
    /* send "this" through WM_CREATE */
    window = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, wnd.lpszClassName, title, 
       WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, width, height,NULL, NULL, 
       GetModuleHandle(NULL), this);

}
```

Comment: The terminology I would use is: `WindowManager::WindowManager` is currently a pointer to member, and `lpfnWndProc` is a pointer to function.

Answer (score 1):

As user1202136 mentioned, C++ class methods have implicit parameter that gets passed into the function whenever it is called. It holds the pointer to the class instance (`this` pointer) and allows you to access the class variables. In order to resolve this issue, you can make the `WindowProcedure` method static and use `GWL_USERDATA` within the window memory to store your class instance (`this` pointer). Look up `GetWindowLongPtr` for more information. When creating the window you'll need to pass `this` pointer via `lpParam` parameter, and store it using `SetWindowLongPtr` when you are handling `WM_CREATE` message.

Answer (score -3):

check solutions:

```
wnd.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WindowProcedure;
```

or

```
LRESULT WNDPROC WindowManager::WindowProcedure(HWND winhan,UINT uint_Message,WPARAM parameter1,LPARAM parameter2)
```

Comment: -1, this is bad or dangerous advice. Attempting to fix an error like this by "casting it away" just hides the problem, it doesn't fix it. Casts on functions should be avoided; they're usually either unnecessary or an indication that there's a bug or other problem. The real problem here is that the WindowProcedure is a member function, but Win32 requires a static function for use as a callback; casting won't help here.

Comment: LRESULT WNDPROC it's standard not dangerous advice, not LRESULT CALLBACK

Comment: "LRESULT WNDPROC ..." doesn't make sense and won't compile; WNDPROC is defined as a pointer to a window procedure; CALLBACK just modifies a function's calling convention. You can combine CALLBACK with a return type, but you can't use "LRESULT WNDPROC" because that's attempting to specify two return types! Anyway, my main point is that you shouldn't cast away problems. If you define your function correctly in the first place, no cast will be needed. (Perhaps the only place that casting a function is valid in Win32 is with GetProcAddress.)